# Framer-Motion: All animations messed up when visit other page or previous page of site

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, framer-motion

I applied Framer-Motion animations to headings, text, and images. They work well on the home page initially, but when I navigate to the **contact** or **about** page, the animations of these pages don't function correctly. Upon returning to the home page, its animations are also disrupted.

[Link to my screen recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pdB0r3fUp6R_CW7KbSh__p98suqTMHA9/view?usp=sharing)

Here is a framer-motion Code of contact page.

```js
const headingVariant = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    y: -300,
    // scale: 0,
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    y: 0,
    // scale: 1,
    transition: {
      duration: 2,
      // mass: 1,
      type: "spring",
      // stiffness: 10,
    },
  },
};

const paraVariant = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    y: 200,
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    y: 0,
    transition: {
      delay: 1.2,
      duration: 1,
    },
  },
};

const formVariant = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    x: 100,
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    x: 0,
    transition: {
      delay: 1.5,
      duration: 1,
    },
  },
};

<motion.h1 variants={headingVariant} initial="hidden" animate="visible">
          Contact Us
</motion.h1>
<motion.p variants={paraVariant} initial="hidden" animate="visible">
  ...content
</motion.p>

<motion.form variants={formVariant} initial="hidden" animate="visible">
 ...content
</motion.form>
```